# How do I change the string on this guitar?

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar

I can't seem to find any pins on the bridge. Although I do believe it has something to do with those things below the bridge.

[image: picture of guitar]

Comment: Okay. I've somehow managed to remove the string from the peg. All i need to know is how I'm supposed to remove it from the bottom bridge.

Comment: It looks like the strings just go through the bridge - you can see the ends of them in that photo. Have you tried just pushing them toward where the camera is? If the string is too kinked to get it through you could clip it off so it's short and then try. What brand/model of guitar is this?

Comment: Are you the same user that posted this question? (https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/64922/can-i-put-nylon-strings-on-a-guitar-designed-for-steel-strings?rq=1)  If so, you should have an admin merge your accounts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to push the string through the hole in the tailpiece until you can get a grip on the round metal thing attached to the end of the string, and pull on that until the string is all the way through the hole. Then feed the new string through the hole and pull it through the tailpiece until the metal thingy catches in the hole.

Comment: Thought so. But for some reason the string is stuck there and i can't seem to push it through. Any hacks i can apply here?

Comment: I've never had that problem... but (similar to what Matt Jones suggested) I'd try cutting the string with a wire cutter, and use a nail or thick needle or something to push the rest through. Also, a bit of lubricant (olive oil, chain spray...) might help.

Comment: Did that. Problem solved...

Comment: @MrMuffinsNoGive if the end of the string has become wedged in the hole you might need to try getting some needle nosed pliers to see if you can get a grip on it and pull.

Comment: @RichardMetzler after some googling I have discovered that those "round metal things" are actually called ball ends!